# WPF how to determine z order for panel containing visualcollection that is an itemshost?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to understand how rendering order works, and as I understand it the rendering engine renders things in order as it progresses the visual tree.

I currently have a Panel that contains a

```
VisualCollection visuals;
```

and overrides the getvisual child function.

```
protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
{
  return visuals[index];
}
protected override int VisualChildrenCount
{
  get
  {
    return visuals.Count;
  }
}
```

However, I am wondering how to manage ZIndex of the items that the panel will be hosting relative to the visual collection.

If there were no visual collection, I could just manage the panel's child controls by setting the Panel.ZIndex on the panel's child controls and on the ItemsControl's Item Style.

And as I understand it, I can control the rendering order of the items in the visualcollection by changing the visual collection's order. However, How do I do both at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position in VisualCollection sets the index of the child element. You cannot change the index after it is added. By default, ZIndex is also set based on this order. However, you can set the ZIndex to another value. That will not change its index in the VisualCollection. They are independent of each other.